# Why doesn't Google Drive API work when called from java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, google-api, servlet-3.0, google-drive-realtime-api

This class works perfectly when I run it separately

```
public class MyDrive {

    private static String CLIENT_ID = "";
    private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "";
    private Drive service;

    public MyDrive() throws IOException {

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
            Arrays.asList(new String[] { DriveScopes.DRIVE }))
            .setAccessType("online").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("");

        // Create a new authorized API client
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                credential).build();

        this.service = service;
    }

    public Drive getDrive() {
        return service;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MyDrive drv = new MyDrive();
    }
}
```

but when I try to create object of this class from Java servlet I get the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
at WorkingServlets.CreateClassroomServlet.doPost(CreateClassroomServlet.java:60)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't think it is problem of jar because that class runs separately correctly. What can be the problem?

Comment: Add the google jars to your servlet's classpath, probably under `.../WEB-INF/lib`

Answer (score 0):

use these dependencies, and try to update project :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.22.0</version>
```

Comment: How can I do that? It's not Maven project. I'm using eclipse IDE